# Magento Payment Method does not ask me for my merchant account

Tags: magento, merchant-account

I am new in magento (magenta 1.9), actually this is my first e-commerce website. 
where I should put my merchant account setting (that e money should transferred to..)

[image: Magento Admin : Payment method saved CC]

Comment: Please explian little more.What type of payment are you trying to set ?

Comment: I am trying to set Saved CC payment method for visa card (which is available in UAE ).

Comment: Bear in mind that saving credit card details means you will need to be PCI DSS compliant - can I suggest based on your question that you don't go down this route, that's for the big boys.  Do as Stony says and install a module to handle your payment gateway if you don't want to use Paypal Pro.  Stripe, Worldpay, Payment Sense, Sagepay etc etc.  Your client has to sign up to a service and they will link that to the client's merchant account.

Comment: @McNab I am totally agree.If you want payment integration then select already added payment methods or use some made extensions for payments.You can't put your details on saved CC.

Comment: so that means Saved CC is not a payment provider, then why magenta needs to fill this form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pay with a creditcard you need a payment provider. There are some Prodiders implemented in Magento. The biggist is Skrill or Paypal but there are a lot of payment provider that have available modules for Magento.

http://de.nr-apps.com/blog/2012/07/23/zahlungsanbieter-ein-uberblick/

here is a list.

Comment: thanks for your help,   but I am asking also should I get my merchant account from financial institution , visa card company or form payment provider (PayPal)